# Upgraded to rails 3.2 and AWS object is nolonger working, how come?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This hasn't got anything to do with paperclip, btw.

I've upgraded to rails 3.2 from a early version of rails 3.

I was using the AWS:S3 class to create buckets and what not.

The following code was working inside a model:

```
AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(:access_key_id => ...blah blah blah
```

I was also requiring the gem in the model like so:

```
require 'aws/s3'
```

However now I've upgraded and have ran all the updates on blunder, I'm getting the error:

```
uninitialized constant AWS::S3::Base
```

...when trying to establish a connection to S3.

Does anyone know what this is happening and how to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you said it doesn't have to do with Paperclip but are you also using Paperclip in addition to the s3 gem in your app? I don't think newer versions of Paperclip depend on the `aws-s3` gem anymore and instead depend on the `aws-sdk` gem.

Try replacing the `aws-s3` gem with the `aws-sdk` gem.

Comment: Both of those gems are in there, but it's still raising an error.

Comment: James is correct.  The issue is that both gems are loaded.  Paperclip replaced aws-s3 with aws-sdk and they are not compatible (namespace collisions). Remove aws-s3 from your Gemfile and replace usage of it with calls via the aws-sdk.

Comment: I have almost the same issue and this DOES NOT fix it.  AWS-SDK does NOT have AWS::S3::Base so AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(:access_key_id => ...blah blah blah does not work even after.